# How can I add spacing between my Bootstrap 5 nav elements?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

So I have this nav using bootstrap 5, and I want to have some space in between each nav-item but still looking good for the phone mode:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav id="navboot" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="Home.php">
      <img src="../Images/Logo.jpg" alt="Logo" width="150px" height="49px">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 ml-1">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Contact
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="tel: +12345">+12345</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="mailto: boutiquethionville@ldlc.com">bla@gmail.com</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" target="_blank">Adress</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Products</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="chart.php">
            <img src="../Images/Shopping-basket.png" alt="" width="45px" height="40px">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="<?= $URL ?>">
            <img src="../Images/Languages.jpg" alt="PT/EN" id="language1">
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[image]

I want this text and img to have more space and not just stay all of them on the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add padding using Bootstrap's spacing attributes, in this case, padding `px`. See: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav id="navboot" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="Home.php">
      <img src="../Images/Logo.jpg" alt="Logo" width="150px" height="49px" />
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 ml-1">
        <li class="nav-item px-4">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown px-4">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Contact
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="tel: +12345">+12345</a></li>
            <li>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="mailto: boutiquethionville@ldlc.com">bla@gmail.com</a
              >
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" target="_blank">Adress</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item px-4">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Products</a
          >
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item px-4">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item px-4">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="chart.php">
            <img src="../Images/Shopping-basket.png" alt="" width="45px" height="40px" />
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item px-4">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="<?= $URL ?>">
            <img src="../Images/Languages.jpg" alt="PT/EN" id="language1" />
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Here I added px-4 for all nav-items, you might need to add a different padding value that suites your requirements (if needed).